# Loop issues with player vs computer pig game

Tags: java

The human section of the game seems to work ok, but as soon as I enter 's' to end the player's turn the code goes into an infinite loop with the computer rolling. It does not loop if the turn ends because of a 1 roll. Can someone point out what I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Proj3Part2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int playerTurnScore = 0;
    int playerTotScore = 0;
    int compTotScore = 0;
    int compTurnScore = 0;
    int turn = 1;
    int dice = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random roll = new Random();
    final int WIN = 20;
    char decision = 'r';
    boolean gameOver = false;
    boolean human = true;

    System.out.print("Your turn total is: " + playerTurnScore + ". Enter <r>oll or <s>top: ");
    decision = input.next().charAt(0);   
while (gameOver == false) {        
while (turn == 1) {            
    if (decision == 'r' || decision == 'R') {
        dice = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        System.out.println("You rolled " + dice);            
        if (dice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Turn over.");
                System.out.println("\nCurrent score: You have " + playerTotScore + ", Computer has " + compTotScore);
                playerTurnScore = 0;
                turn = 2;
            }                
            else {
                playerTurnScore +=dice;
                System.out.print("Your turn total is " + playerTurnScore + ". Enter <roll> or <s>top ");
                decision = input.next().charAt(0);                   

                }                
            }               
    else {
                System.out.print("Turn over.");
                System.out.println("\nCurrent score: You have " + (playerTotScore += playerTurnScore) + ", Computer has " + compTotScore);
                playerTurnScore = 0;
                turn = 2;

            }    
    if (playerTotScore >= WIN) {
            System.out.println("\nYou win!");
            gameOver = true;               
            }              
}

while (turn == 2) { //computer turn
        System.out.print("Computer turn total is: " + compTurnScore);
        System.out.println(" Computer rolls.");
         dice = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        System.out.println("Computer rolled: " + dice);
        counter++;
    if (dice == 1) {
                System.out.print("Turn over.");
                System.out.println("\nCurrent score: You have " + playerTotScore + ", Computer has " + compTotScore);
                compTurnScore = 0;
                turn = 1; 
                break;
            }           
    if (counter < 3) {
                compTurnScore += dice;
                dice = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;    
                counter++;
            }                
        if (counter >= 3) {
            compTurnScore += dice;
            System.out.print("Turn over.");
            compTotScore += compTurnScore;
            System.out.println("\nCurrent score: You have " + playerTotScore + ", Computer has " + compTotScore);
            turn = 1;
           break; 
    }        
}
}
 System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stepping through the code in the debugger I can see you have

```
System.out.print("Your turn total is " + playerTurnScore + ". Enter <roll> or <s>top ");
decision = input.next().charAt(0);
```

in your first loop so it asks what to do next, however you don't have this in your second loop.

Comment: I'm confused about how to add that since the computer's turn shouldn't require any outside input, correct?

Comment: @NikkiHarding however after the computer has rolled, you need to ask the human what happens next or you have an infinite loop.